# System wont boot. Stuck at "/dev/sda5: clean, XXXX/XXXX files, YYYY/YYYY blocks

Tags: boot

My PC won't seem to boot up. When I turn it on, I am greeted by this screen.

[image: boot]

I use a LiveCD to try gparted on the disk and everything looked green

[image]

What could I do?

Comment: Your PC not booting up has nothing to do with the file system. All is well there: something else must be wrong. Try pressing ESC on bootup to see more messages.

Comment: @Jos I thought about it too, but sadly pressing ESC won't do anything. I don't get any other information, and I cannot get to that screen with the "OK"s and "FAILED"s